# How to set $_POST values in Node JS child process

Tags: php, node.js, amazon-web-services, http-post, child-process

I hosted my Slim app on AWS Lambda. For my PHP app to work, I followed [this tutorial](https://cwhite.me/hosting-a-laravel-application-on-aws-lambda/)

My app runs fine until I try to submit a form with a POST method. My PHP cannot get the values from the form. When I dumped **$_POST** and **file_get_contents('php://input')**, both returned a *null*.

In the tutorial, Chris (the author) stated that this code spawns the child process and sets a bunch of environment variables which PHP CGI populates into the $_SERVER super global.

```
var php = spawn('./php-cgi', ['function.php'], {
  env: Object.assign({
      REDIRECT_STATUS: 200,
      REQUEST_METHOD: requestMethod,
      SCRIPT_FILENAME: 'function.php',
      SCRIPT_NAME: '/function.php',
      PATH_INFO: '/',
      SERVER_NAME: serverName,
      SERVER_PROTOCOL: 'HTTP/1.1',
      REQUEST_URI: requestUri
  }, headers)
});
```

I am not familiar with child processes, so I would like to ask if there is a way that I can also populate the **$_POST** superglobal? Because I think the POST data lives in the **event** object/variable in my handler function, meaning (I think) my NodeJS wrapper could access the POST data, but it didn't pass it to the PHP CGI?

```
exports.handler = function(event, context)
```

here is the full code of my NodeJS wrapper:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var parseHeaders, parseResponse, parseStatusLine;

parseResponse = function(responseString) {
  var headerLines, line, lines, parsedStatusLine, response;
  response = {};
  lines = responseString.split('\r\n');
  parsedStatusLine = parseStatusLine(lines.shift());
  response['protocolVersion'] = parsedStatusLine['protocol'];
  response['statusCode'] = parsedStatusLine['statusCode'];
  response['statusMessage'] = parsedStatusLine['statusMessage'];
  headerLines = [];
  while (lines.length > 0) {
    line = lines.shift();
    if (line === "") {
      break;
    }
    headerLines.push(line);
  }
  response['headers'] = parseHeaders(headerLines);
  response['body'] = lines.join('\r\n');
  return response;
};

parseHeaders = function(headerLines) {
  var headers, key, line, parts, _i, _len;
  headers = {};
  for (_i = 0, _len = headerLines.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    line = headerLines[_i];
    parts = line.split(":");
    key = parts.shift();
    headers[key] = parts.join(":").trim();
  }
  return headers;
};

parseStatusLine = function(statusLine) {
  var parsed, parts;
  parts = statusLine.match(/^(.+) ([0-9]{3}) (.*)$/);
  parsed = {};
  if (parts !== null) {
    parsed['protocol'] = parts[1];
    parsed['statusCode'] = parts[2];
    parsed['statusMessage'] = parts[3];
  }
  return parsed;
};

exports.index = function(event, context) {

    // Sets some sane defaults here so that this function doesn't fail when it's not handling a HTTP request from
    // API Gateway.
    var requestMethod = event.httpMethod || 'GET';
    var serverName = event.headers ? event.headers.Host : '';
    var requestUri = event.path || '';
    var headers = {};

    // Convert all headers passed by API Gateway into the correct format for PHP CGI. This means converting a header
    // such as "X-Test" into "HTTP_X-TEST".
    if (event.headers) {
        Object.keys(event.headers).map(function (key) {
            headers['HTTP_' + key.toUpperCase()] = event.headers[key];
        });
    }

    // Spawn the PHP CGI process with a bunch of environment variables that describe the request.
    var php = spawn('./php-cgi', ['slim/public/index.php'], {
        env: Object.assign({
            REDIRECT_STATUS: 200,
            REQUEST_METHOD: requestMethod,
            SCRIPT_FILENAME: 'slim/public/index.php',
            SCRIPT_NAME: '/index.php',
            PATH_INFO: '/',
            SERVER_NAME: serverName,
            SERVER_PROTOCOL: 'HTTP/1.1',
            REQUEST_URI: requestUri
        }, headers)
    });

    // Listen for output on stdout, this is the HTTP response.
    var response = '';
    php.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        response += data.toString('utf-8');
    });

    // When the process exists, we should have a complete HTTP response to send back to API Gateway.
    php.on('close', function(code) {
        // Parses a raw HTTP response into an object that we can manipulate into the required format.
        var parsedResponse = parseResponse(response);

        // Signals the end of the Lambda function, and passes the provided object back to API Gateway.
        context.succeed({
            statusCode: parsedResponse.statusCode || 200,
            headers: parsedResponse.headers,
            body: parsedResponse.body
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: How about `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));`?

Comment: I tried that, too. I forgot to include that in my question. It also returned a null.

Comment: Try passing variables as querystring? `function.php?x=y`

Comment: @OzgurGUL I don't think that's safe to do with passwords? But I may have found a solution. I populated an element of the $_SERVER superglobal. the QUERY_STRING element. I assigned the event.body there so that I could access the values in the back-end. But I do not know if it's safe or efficient.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases it's necessary to set CONTENT_LENGTH and/or CONTENT_TYPE in the environment in order for php-cgi to process $_POST properly. 
For example (where postBody is a string like "field1=value1&field2=value2"):

```
var env = {
    'SCRIPT_FILENAME': script_path, 
    'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST',
    'REDIRECT_STATUS': 1,  
    'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
    'CONTENT_LENGTH': postBody.length  
}

//if the URL has anything after "?", it should appear in $_GET even when the method is "POST"
if(queryString) env['QUERY_STRING'] = queryString;
```

The post body needs to be input into the stdin of the child.
Here is an async example:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn; 
var phpProcess = spawn (php_cgi_path, [script_path], {'env': env})
phpProcess.stdin.write( postBody );

var outputBuffer = []; 
phpProcess.stdout.on('data', function(data) { 
    outputBuffer.push (data.toString()); 
}) 
phpProcess.stdout.on('end', function( ) { 
    var phpOutput = outputBuffer.join('') ; 
    // process php output
});
```

It's also possible to give the input data in a synchronous way, for example:

```
var spawnSync = require('child_process').spawnSync; 
var phpProcessSync = spawnSync (php_cgi_path, [script_path], {'env': env, 'input': postBody})
var phpOutput = phpProcessSync.stdout.toString()
// process php output
```

Again the post data is input separately from "env".

It's also possible to modify the script so that it populates $_FILES as well.
For example, one can use Uint8Array (instead of string) to store post body, then set 'CONTENT_TYPE' to `request.headers['content-type']` 
(Then we would have for example `"Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarynGa8p8HMIQ8kWQLA"`)
then use `phpProcess.stdin.write( Buffer.from(postBody) );`
It will have "tmp_name" etc in the $_FILES variable.